# Shell Prompt Colors on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, mac, bash, terminal, shell

I'm trying to add colors and customize the shell prompt on OS X Lion so I edited .bashrc and I can only see the differences for the root account. So, after I edit the .bashrc with:

```
PS1="[\u][\w] :"
```

and run the terminal I get

```
Phil:~ phil$ sudo -s
[root][~] :
```

but I only see the difference in the root account. How can I fix this?

I want to display:

```
[Phil][~] : sudo -s
[root][~] :
```

Comment: You could try ZSH (or a different shell). I know it has all sorts of colors and customizations. If you just want to edit bash, I would recommend changing the question to "add olors and customize *bash* on OS X Lion).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to edit the file `.bash_profile` in your home directory, i.e. `/Users/username/.bash_profile`.

Comment: Note: ~/.bash_profile is run by login shells. ~/.bashrc is run by non-login shells. To ensure customizations work with both login and non-login shells, put common customizations in ~/.bashrc and have ~/.bash_profile run that with: `if [ -f $HOME/.bashrc ]; then . $HOME/.bashrc fi`

Comment: Terminal creates login shells by default. If you run `bash` from a login shell, that creates a non-login shell. Sub-shells are non-login shells by default.